# Failed to Integrate TailwindCSS with NextJS Because of postcss.config.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have successfully migrated from vite to NextJS, following the official instructions. When I tried to integrate tailwindcss next, the error occurred as the following picture after doing everything the official document said.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD4B7.png)

After tries and errors, I have found that the error comes from postcss.config.js, but I have no clues on how to solve the issue. The error is gone as long as I don't have the postcss.config.js file, but I still can't get tailwind CSS to work without that config file. I've tried to run the dev server locally and with docker, both of which get me no luck. I cannot find any issue closely related to mine. Please help me with this one.

These are the code I have related to the issue.

1. postcss.config.js

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

2. tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": { "@/*": ["/*"] },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "plugins": [{ "name": "next" }]
  },
  "include": ["./dist/types/**/*.ts", "./next-env.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/"]
}
```

3.next.config.mjs

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export", // Outputs a Single-Page Application (SPA).
  distDir: "./dist", // Changes the build output directory to `./dist/`.
};

export default nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tailwind CSS` is a plugin for `PostCSS`. So, you'll have to install `postcss` package and set up the configuration with `postcss.config.js` file. When you're working on a `Next.js` project and would like to use `Tailwind CSS` in it, `tailwindcss`, `postcss`, and `autoprefixer` is a typical combination of libraries that you'll have to install.

Based upon the context and error message that you shared, here are some considerations that you may have to check in:

1. Install `postcss` and `autoprefixer` packages as dev dependencies:

   ```
   npm install postcss --save-dev
   npm install autoprefixer --save-dev
   ```
2. Set up `postcss.config.js` file (I assume you already set up
   `tailwind.config.js` file too):

   ```
   module.exports = {
     plugins: {
       tailwindcss: {},
       autoprefixer: {},
     },
   };
   ```
3. The error message also indicates that there is a compatibility issue with using `require()` to your `postcss.config.js` in a context
   where ES Modules (ESM) are expected. So, consider converting your
   `postcss.config.js` to ESM syntax, and rename your
   `postcss.config.js` file to `postcss.config.mjs`. If all these steps
   don't resolve your issue, try applying the same step to your
   `tailwind.config.js` file too. The updated `postcss.config.mjs` file
   would look like:

   ```
   export default {
     plugins: {
       tailwindcss: {},
       autoprefixer: {},
     },
   };
   ```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed instructions. I'm afraid your suggestion's help is limited because that's the same as the official documentation. As I mentioned in the description, I've followed the documentation, and yet the problem still persists.

Comment: But, based upon the context and error message that you shared, I can't get deeper understanding of your project's specific issue. Actually, the steps in my answer are typical way in `next.js` projects, and the code for `postcss.config.js` that I shared is what I have been always using in my `next.js` projects without any issues. To better assist you for your unique issue, I'd need more context and codes of your project, especially for `post.config.js`, `tsconfig.js` or `jsconfig.js`, and `next.config.js` files.

Comment: I have added the code. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Ok, i will have a look. In the meantime, I've just updated my answer as well. Try applying them to your project and let me know if that works.